# How to place Relative Layout at the bottom always

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

MY XMl code looks like :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="430dp"
  android:fadingEdge="none"
  >    
  <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/descriptionanth"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/searchjobslayout"
  >
      <ImageView android:id="@+id/homeimage_one" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/logoblack"></ImageView>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">




     <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/keywords"
     android:text="Search by keyword:"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="14sp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textColor="#000000"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     ></TextView>

     <EditText
      android:id="@+id/keywordsedit"
      android:hint="  Enter KeyWords"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="32dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
      android:textSize="14sp"
      android:background="@drawable/text_field"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:textColor="#000000"
     ></EditText>

      <Button
     android:id="@+id/search"
     android:text="Search"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="35dp"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:background="@drawable/buttonclick"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

     android:textSize="20sp"
     ></Button>

     <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/browseby"
     android:text="Browse by:"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="14sp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textColor="#000000"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:paddingTop="10dp"></TextView>




    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >


    <Button 
     android:id="@+id/jobsbycity"
     android:text="City"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="30dp"

     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:background="@drawable/buttonclick"

     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textSize="15sp"
     ></Button>


    <Button 
     android:id="@+id/jobsbytype"
     android:text="Category"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="30dp"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

     android:background="@drawable/buttonclick"
     android:layout_below="@id/jobsbycity"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

     android:textSize="15sp"
     ></Button>

      <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/signin"
     android:text="Signed in as"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="12sp"

     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:layout_below="@id/jobsbytype"
     android:paddingTop="10dp"></TextView>

     <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/signinas"
     android:text="mail_id"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="12sp"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:textColor="#000000"

     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:layout_below="@id/signin"
     android:paddingTop="5dp"></TextView>

     <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/logout"
     android:text="Sign out"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="13sp"

     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:textColor="#000000"
      android:layout_below="@id/signinas"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:textStyle="bold" ></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>





    </LinearLayout>

     <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

     <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

     <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

     <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

     <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

     <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

     <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

     <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

     <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />

     <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    />
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tabbarbottom"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"


    >

  <Button
     android:id="@+id/jobs"
     android:text="About Us"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:textColor="@drawable/white"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"

     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textSize="12.5sp"
     ></Button>

     <Button
     android:id="@+id/aboutus"
     android:text="Value"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:textColor="@drawable/white"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/jobs"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textSize="12.5sp"
     ></Button>

     <Button
     android:id="@+id/benefits"
     android:text="History"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:textColor="@drawable/white"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/aboutus"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textSize="12.5sp"
     ></Button>

    </RelativeLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

I want to place the relative layout (last relative layout which having 3 buttons it, after scrollview ) at the bottom my screen. but its not happening

what to do??

**Edited:** `The happening is i statically placed the relative layout by specifying padding, when running in portrait mode i made it fix at bottom but when i changed to landscape its not at bottom. How to place relativelayout in bottom in either cases??`

Thanks

Comment: You say *its not happening*. What is happening? Is the RelativeLayout scrolled off screen? Is it appearing at the top? Is it not showing? Is something else showing up after it? Be more specific in your description of what is going wrong: in general you want to 1) Say what you are trying to do (which you did) 2) Say how you are trying to do it (which you did) 3) Say what you expected to happen (which you did) 4) Say what actually happened that is different from what you expected (which you didn't).

Comment: OMG! whatever this is it seems to have too many layouts (not counting the views within them) to be efficient :). Just curious how long does it take to load and refresh?

Comment: The happening is i statically placed the relative layout by specifying padding, when running in portrait mode i made it fix at bottom but when i changed to landscape its not at bottom. How to place relativelayout in bottom in either cases??

Comment: Use android:layout_marginTop=""  in ur relativelayout and change these two lines  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" instead of fillparent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the solution I tested and which works :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" android:fadingEdge="none">
    ...
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="60dip" 
        android:background="@drawable/tabbarbottom">

        <Button android:id="@+id/jobs" android:text="About Us"
            android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            ...></Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/aboutus" android:text="Value"
            android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            ...></Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/benefits" android:text="History"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" ...></Button>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

- The first LinearLayout should have `layout_height="fill_parent"`.
  This way it takes up the whole screen.
- The ScrollView should have a
  small fixed height, and an extra `android:layout_weight="1.0"` : it
  will take up whatever space is remaining.
- The RelativeLayout should
  have a fixed height (it will always take up the same space at the
  bottom of the screen), and the Buttons inside of it should have
  `layout_height="fill_parent"` (to have the same height as the
  RelativeLayout).

Answer (score 3):

Add following line to your Relative layout

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

This must be work.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Make parent layout as relative layout. layout which contain button put that on bottom using

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

This will work

Answer (score 1):

In the ScrollView

```
android:fillViewport="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

@Udaykiran Hey Your Code for XMl is ok please check here i put your code with some change and i found only one change in this Relative Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="horizontal" 
                                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

please change this than try

here is xml with with out resources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="430dp"
    android:fadingEdge="none">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_screen_large_long_land"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/searchjobslayout">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/homeimage_one"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ImageView>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/keywords" android:text="Search by keyword:"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"></TextView>

            <EditText android:id="@+id/keywordsedit" android:hint="  Enter KeyWords"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"></EditText>

            <Button android:id="@+id/search" android:text="Search"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"></Button>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/browseby" android:text="Browse by:"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:paddingTop="10dp"></TextView>




            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <Button android:id="@+id/jobsbycity" android:text="City"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="30dp"

                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="15sp"></Button>


                <Button android:id="@+id/jobsbytype" android:text="Category"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_below="@id/jobsbycity"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textSize="15sp"></Button>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/signin" android:text="Signed in as"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_below="@id/jobsbytype" android:paddingTop="10dp"></TextView>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/signinas" android:text="mail_id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textColor="#000000" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_below="@id/signin" android:paddingTop="5dp"></TextView>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/logout" android:text="Sign out"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="13sp" android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_below="@id/signinas"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
            </RelativeLayout>





        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <Button android:id="@+id/jobs" android:text="About Us"
        android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12.5sp"></Button>

    <Button android:id="@+id/aboutus" android:text="Value"
        android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/jobs" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="12.5sp"></Button>

    <Button android:id="@+id/benefits" android:text="History"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/aboutus" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="12.5sp"></Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```